# android google maps get place details and send them to another activity

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to send place details to another activity but i get errors like Cannot resolve methods'getApplication(), Cannot resolve methods 'startActivity(android.content.Intent). Below is the code that i have tried so far.

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;



    public class GetNearbyPlacesData extends AsyncTask<Object, String, 
    String> {

    String googlePlacesData;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    String url;


    @Override
     protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
      try {
        Log.d("GetNearbyPlacesData", "doInBackground entered");
        mMap = (GoogleMap) params[0];
        url = (String) params[1];
        DownloadUrl downloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();
        googlePlacesData = downloadUrl.readUrl(url);
        Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "doInBackground Exit");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", e.toString());
    }
       return googlePlacesData;
    }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         try {
        Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "onPostExecute Entered");
        List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList = null;
        DataParser dataParser = new DataParser();
        nearbyPlacesList =  dataParser.parse(result);
        ShowNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlacesList);
        Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "onPostExecute Exit");
       } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }

      private void ShowNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> 
      nearbyPlacesList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nearbyPlacesList.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("onPostExecute","Entered into showing locations");
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = nearbyPlacesList.get(i);
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lat"));
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lng"));
        final String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
        final String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");
        String phone = googlePlace.get("phone_number");
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity + phone);
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);




        markerOptions.icon
        (BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptor
         Factory.HUE_RED));
        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));

        // Called when the user clicks a marker of any place.
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new 
        GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(), 
              Placedetails.class);
                //sends this to the next activity
                i.putExtra("placename", placeName);
                i.putExtra("vici", vicinity);
                i.putExtra("title", marker.getTitle());
                startActivity(i);
            }
           });

         }
        }


     }
```

Comment: `getApplication`, `startActivity`, and `getApplicationContext` are all methods of `Context` class. You are trying to call them from an `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a **constructor** of your `GetNearbyPlacesData` class.

```
private Context context;

public GetNearbyPlacesData(Context context){
    this.context=new WeakReference<Context>(context);
}
```

Then pass the **context** of your activity as below from corresponding activity:

```
new GetNearbyPlacesData(this).execute();
```

**Modify** `onInfoWindoeClick()` as below:

```
  @Override
  public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Placedetails.class);  //sends this to the next activity
        i.putExtra("placename", placeName);
        i.putExtra("vici", vicinity);
        i.putExtra("title", marker.getTitle());
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
   });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wrap it in a `WeakReference` to not cause a memory leak.

Comment: As far as I know `WeakReference` is used as last resort.

Comment: Its actually a pretty common pattern to avoid memory leaks. In this case if the passed `Context` is an application context its fine. If its an `Activity`'s context and the `Activity` is destroyed while the `AsyncTask` is running, the GC cannot remove it from the heap because the AsyncTask has a strong reference its context. This is wasted heap space. Wrapping it in a `WeakReference` allows the GC to remove it from the heap if need be.

Answer (score 0):

When we `startActivity(i)` from outside activity context then we have to set flag.

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, YourNewActivity.class); 
 i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
 context.startActivity(i);
```